# JavaFX - How to close a Tab

Tags: java, javafx

Is there a method of some sort for closing a `Tab` in JavaFX?
I'm looking for something similar to the one that's available to the `Stage` class (See the example 1).

So far the only known way to close a `Tab` through code seems to be by calling `getOnCloseRequest` or `getOnClosed` event manually and removing the `Tab` from it's `TabPane` (See the example 2).

#### Example 1:

```
private void closeWindow(Stage stage)
{
   stage.close();
}
```

#### Example 2

```
private void closeFirstTab(TabPane tabPane)
{
    Tab tab = tabPane.getTabs().get(0);
    EventHandler handler = tab.getOnCloseRequest();

    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler.handle(null);
    }
}

private void onClose(Event e, TabPane tabPane, Tab tab)
{
    if (e != null)
    {
        e.consume();
    }

    System.out.println("onClose");
    tabPane.getTabs().remove(tab);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `tabPane.getTabs()` method returns the collection of tabs in the `TabPane`. So if you call

```
tabPane.getTabs().remove(0)
```

or whichever index you choose, that should delete it from the stored tabs and stop it from displaying.